# How to Defer third party Offscreen Images in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to improve the speed of my website but there are many issues with that the speed not improving but i do not know how to resolve this can ant of one  please help me for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHBfu.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading

Comment: You can also preload images using this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/preload-images/

Comment: Thank s for reply i already use WP rocket plugin but still not sure how to resolve this errors.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to lazy load the images in WordPress is to use the [Lazy Load plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rocket-lazy-load/). It works good with your WP rocket plugin too.

However, if you would like to lazy load the images manually, I suggest you visit [this tutorial](https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-lazy-load/#Adding_Lazy_Load_Without_a_Plugin).